# PHP returns JSON fine but JavaScript shows it is undefined in onload function

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest, undefined

I can't figure out how to solve this problem so I'm asking you to help me with it.

I'm trying to parse RSS feed to JSON, but due to XSS problems it can't be done with JS (I'm not using jQuery so don't recommend me plugins). I thought I'll do this with PHP help and wrote some code to get url, parse it, some loops etc. and it returns proper JSON object with array inside of it and it can be seen in Chrome DevTools under Network section.

Problem is that JavaScript shows me that response text is undefined. I've been trying to solve this for 3 hours and I can't figure it out.

Here's the JS code:

```
        this.fetchNews = function ( feed ) {

            var method = 'GET';
            var url = 'feed.php';
            var target = encodeURIComponent( feed );
            var params = '?target=' + target;

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open( method, url + params, true );
            request.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' );
            request.onload = function () {

                if ( request.readyState === 4 ) {
                    if ( request.status === 200 ) {

                        console.error( this.reponseText );
                        var list = this.reponseText;
                        for ( var i in list ) {
                            i.push( self.news.list );
                        }

                        console.error( self.newst.list );
                    }
                }
            };
            request.send( null );
        };
        this.fetchNews.call( this, 'http://phys.org/rss-feed/&num=20' );
```

And here's PHP:

```
$url = $_GET['target'];
$xml = file_get_contents( $url );
$feed = simplexml_load_string( $xml );

$output = array(
    'items' => array()
);
$items = $feed->channel[0];
$i = 0;

foreach ( $items->item as $item ) {

    $title = $item->title;
    $title = (String)$title;
    $output['items'][$i++] = $title;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

Comment: Don't bother yourself with that type-o in last console.error, it doesn't matter at all. And I'm using error because I have a lot of console.logs and I'm so lazy I can't make myself delete them :)

Comment: You never parse the JSON to an object, not sure how you'd iterate a string, but are you saying the first log with `this.reponseText` is undefined, if so posting the PHP would probably be a good idea ?

Comment: Also, this looks like it's open to attacks, just opening the console and calling the function with a malicious URL would download anything to the server, and wether that is an issue or not depends on what you do with the downloaded content, but be aware.

Comment: In this case I don't really care about secutiry, because it will sit on my local server on Raspberry Pi, I'm making a Magic Mirror which I want to show me news from RSS channels. PHP added above :)

Comment: Try replacing `request.onload` with `request.onreadystatechange` and move the `open()` after the function, just above `send()`. Also make sure the PHP actually outputs something, for instance try hardcoding a small JSON string as the returned data to see that it works

Comment: Weird thing is that I have almost the same function somewhere else to get weather status from openweathermaps.com and it works fine.

Comment: Do you try to set the header to JSON?

Something like this in your PHP file:

`header('Content-type:application/json');`

Comment: Actually they are set, this editor must have cut that part out it's: header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeeeez I'm an idiot, I wrote `this.reponseText` instead of `this.responseText`. Sorry for troubles...